# Can't render template, getting page not found (404) Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I can't seem to find the error, site works fine but when I request http://127.0.0.1:8000/test I get the 404 error, I feel so stupid I'm really stuck on this, please help:(

Error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/test

Using the URLconf defined in project4.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    [name='index']
    login [name='login']
    logout [name='logout']
    register [name='register']
    posts-json/ [name='posts-view-json']
    ^network/static/(?P<path>.*)$
    ^media/(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, test, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

This is my urls

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views
from .views import post_view_json, profile_test_view


urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("test/", profile_test_view, name="test"),

    # endpoints
    path("posts-json/", post_view_json, name="posts-view-json")
]


urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It's a social website and I'm trying to render the posts and user's profiles on a page.

My views

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.core import serializers

from .models import User, Post, Profile

def index(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'hello': 'hello world!',
        'qs':qs,
    }
    return render(request, "network/index.html", context)


def post_view_json(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()
    data = serializers.serialize('json', qs)
    return JsonResponse({'data': data})

def profile_test_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, "network/profile_test.html", {'profile':profile})
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a trailing slash in `urls.py` but not in the URL you are calling.

Either change `urls.py` like this:

```py
...
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("test", profile_test_view, name="test"), # <-- NOTE: I removed the slash here

    # endpoints
    path("posts-json/", post_view_json, name="posts-view-json")
]
...
```

or call `http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/` <-- NOTE: slash added

Comment: I tried both and neither worked, same error @dacx

Comment: It worked when I restarted the server, thanks